# Top trending online video with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the

1. top trending online videos in Singapore
2. most engaged Facebook posts in Singapore
   and get their likes, shares and comments, etc.?

If yes any pointer on the right API to achieve the purpose?

Comment: No, Facebook does not provide this kind of information via their own APIs.

Comment: @CBroe Be it free and paid version?

Comment: There is no “paid version” of Facebook’s APIs to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Say if we know 10 public pages that are most popular, is it possible to monitor only those pages, and get the online videos/posts within with top trending/most engaged?

Comment: Your app would need the Page Public Content Access feature to be able to access content on pages you have no admin access to, but the allowed usage for that is only to “provide competitive benchmark analysis”, so I doubt Facebook would approve it for what you want to build here.